# JSON content shows a blank window for Tiptap-Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, tiptap

#### Background

I'm using [tiptap-vuetify](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify) to implement a message/chat UI where users see an editable Tiptap instance for creating new messages as well as several uneditable Tiptap instances (one for each already-sent message in the thread the user is viewing).

[image]

I have the editable instance output data in JSON format, which I store in my database in a JSONB field.

#### Problem

When I load the JSON for sent messages from the database, only plaintext messages show up; if I applied any kind of styling (bold, italics, lists, etc.), nothing at all shows up.

[image]

The code I'm using for the uneditable Tiptap instances is this:

```
<tiptap-vuetify
  v-model="message.content"
  :editor-properties="{ editable: false }"
  output-format="json"
/>
```

Here's a screenshot of the `message` object (and `message.content`) for the "bold asdf" example above:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the fix:

1. I didn't realize I needed to include the `:extensions` prop for all of the HTML features I wanted to use (bold, italic, etc.) in the editor that would *render* the HTML.  I thought those extensions were just used to add the toolbar buttons, but they are also used to render the JSON that those buttons produce.
2. To then hide the toolbar, I just used the example toolbar-slot code from the readme, and the toolbar was gone.

Here's the working code:

```
<tiptap-vuetify
  v-model="message.content"
  :extensions="extensions"
  :editor-properties="{ editable: false }"
>
  <template #toolbar="{ buttons }">
    <pre>{{ buttons }}</pre>
  </template>
</tiptap-vuetify>
```

Answer (score 0):

When i was looking in the documentation -> [Get started](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify#get-started)
I see that the content is HTML.
As it usually is inside any tiptap.

Your content data is an object with alot of nested data. I don't think the plugin/component can handle that type of format.

Try save your data as HTML to your .json and there for also fetch the data as HTML from your .json.

Example:

```json
{
  messages: [
    { 
      "id": 1,
      "content": "<p>foo bar</p>"
    },

    { 
      "id": 2,
      "content": "<p>hello world</p>"
    },
  ]

}
```

(New to answer questions on stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you look at the Tiptap documentation, it seems to say that supplying JSON as the content should work: https://tiptap.dev/api/commands/set-content/ "The setContent command replaces the document with a new one. You can pass JSON or HTML, both work fine. It’s basically the same as setting the content on initialization."